# git log filename error: ambiguous argument filename unknown revision

Tags: git

I'm using git bash to check the commit history of a filename under a repo's root folder, but the following error appears:

```
git log filename
```

> ambiguous argument 'extract_frebnd_cwt.m': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Commands below generate the same error:

```
git log -p extract_fre_bnd.m
git log -p feature analysis/extract_fre_bnd.m
```

Comment: Note that this occurs because Git is not sure how to treat the string `extract_fre_bnd.m`: is it a branch name like `master`, or a file name, or ...?  The `--` argument tells `git log`: *everything after this point is a file name* which resolves its dilemma and allows it to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

To get the log of a single file try this: `git log -- PATH/TO/FILE`. To limit results to 10 commits use `git log -n10 -- PATH/TO/FILE`

Comment: Thanks very much! You are right. I found out my problem is:1.ignore the full path to the file under the current folder; 2.when I try to add the fullpath like git log -p  path/filename, I forget that we need a ' ' when there is a space within path.

Comment: I forgot to mention `--follow` is sometimes useful if files are renamed.